# Why is this not a complex variable?

Tags: complex-numbers, theta-functions

I'm watching [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GQFljOVZ7I) about the *Jacobi Theta Function* on YouTube.

At around 6:14 in the video, he has shown that...

$$\vartheta (x) =
\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} e^{-\pi {n^2} x} =
\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} {e^{-\pi {k^2} {1\over x}}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {e^{-\pi x \big( y+ i {k\over x}\big)^2}} \space dy$$

I understand the steps he took to get to this point. But here is where I got confused.

He then looked at $y + i {k\over x}$ and he Let...

$y + i {k\over x} = z$

But then he said...

$dy = dz$

Because $i {k\over x}$ is not a complex variable.

I don't understand why it isn't. Isn't a complex number defined as $a+bi$ where $a,b\in \mathbb R$?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Integration is performed w.r.t. $y$, so $x$ is treated as constant.

Comment: @MathMajor Thank you...I took it with respect to $x$ for some reason haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x$ is being held constant, the only thing varying in $z$ is $y$.

Comment: Ahhh I see my mistake. I was looking at it with respect to $x$.